# is it feasible to have a custom i18n label notation in JSPs?

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization

Currently, to internationalize its labels, one would do like such:

```
<div title="<spring:message code="accountTitle"/>"><spring:message code="accountDescription"/></a>
```

But It's too long in my opinion, and the markup is confusing and difficult to read inside html, especially with attributes. I would like to have something among these lines:

```
<div title="$T{accountTitle}">$T{accountDescription}</a>
```

How to implement such a thing in Java/Jsp/Spring ? (or maybe it already exists?)

Answer (score 1):

You could define custom tags for that, but that might be too much work for just translations.

Or you could just follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717539/136363 and put the `MessageSource` into session and call it on JSP to solve this particular problem.